# Can I change the default path folder when generate pdf using pdfkit?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I have done generate PDF using pdfkit in node js, but the pdf is downloaded in the default folder download in my computer. Can I change the path of folder from node js, not from setting in my computer?

If needed this is my code

```
this.downloadPdf = function(req, res, next) {
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const blobStream = require('blob-stream');

let pdfDoc = new PDFDocument;
const stream = pdfDoc.pipe(blobStream());
var pdfname = 'SPK';
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename='+ pdfname +'.pdf');

generateHeader(pdfDoc, address, telp_branch, fax)

pdfDoc.fontSize(10)
.text("Data Pembeli", 15, 100)

pdfDoc.fontSize(10)
.text("Detail Pembelian", 15, 281)

displayImage(pdfDoc, ttd_sales, ttd_cust);

pdfDoc.pipe(res);

pdfDoc.end();
};
```

Using the code above, the downloaded pdf automatically goes to the download folder, i want to change the folder using the node js code. Thankyou very much for all the help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so like this

```
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf')); // write to PDF
```

For further information check this docs:
http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html

Comment: if I change doc.pipe(res) to doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf')); the pdf can not downloaded just loading

Comment: thankyouu it's work for me i use both of the doc.pipe(res) and doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf'));